# Pandas: not sure if this is a pivot or stack or whether there is a built in function for this

Tags: pandas, stack, pivot

I have a dataframe with two columns and have tried to pivot them:

```
arr = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6]])
arr.pivot(columns=0)
```

This doesn't give me my desired output, which is a list of values from column 2 for each unique value in column 1 like this:

```
output = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2,3],[1,4,5,6]])
```

I am sure that pandas has a function for this and have tried looking it up but haven't been able to find it.

Comment: did your query solved?

Comment: yes working as intended. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `groupby()`+`cumcount()` then `pivot()`+`rename_axis()`:

```
arr[2]=arr.groupby(0).cumcount()
#Finally:
out=arr.pivot(0,2,1).rename_axis(columns=None,index=None)
```

Now if you print `out` you will get your expected output